# Is it security wise to apply session regenerate id in all php pages

Tags: php

Am trying to prevent session hijacking and other forms of csrf attack on my site and everything seems to be working fine.

My question is that I have `session_regenerate_id();`
on both **index.php** and **save.php** files

Am I still protected against session hijacking and fixation attack etc or should I just remove
`session_regenerate_id();` 
from **index.php**

**index.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
 //$token= md5(uniqid());

$token = md5(uniqid().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $_SESSION['update_token']= $token;
 session_write_close();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="save.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**save.php**

```
 <?php
     session_start();

     session_regenerate_id();
     $token = $_SESSION['update_token'];
     unset($_SESSION['update_token']);
     session_write_close();

     if ($_POST['token']==$token) {
       // insert into database via PDO
     } else {
       // session attack detected.
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.md#user-content-renew-the-session-id-after-any-privilege-level-change and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Management

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus. This really solve my problem

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped!